# firefox addon, how to modify(change) the url before the request is sent (even made) by the browser?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to remove some parameters in a url, currently my code:

```
require("sdk/tabs").on("ready", removeList);

function removeList(tab) {
    var index = tab.url.indexOf("&list=");
    if (tab.url.indexOf("youtube.com") > -1 && index > -1) {
        console.log(tab.url);
        var temp = tab.url.slice(0, index);
        console.log(temp);
        tab.url = "";
        tab.url = temp;
    }
}
```

But it will send two urls(requests) to the server, the original one (I can see the response without the video being played) and the truncated one(as expected).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two options are `http-on-modify-request` and `http-on-opening-request`. The first is fine, but the second fires earlier and you lose a lot of a ability. The first method the url is fine because server never sees it.

```
const { Ci, Cu, Cc, Cr } = require('chrome'); //const {interfaces: Ci, utils: Cu, classes: Cc, results: Cr } = Components;
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/devtools/Console.jsm');

var observers = {
    'http-on-examine-response': {
        observe: function (aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
            console.info('http-on-modify-request: aSubject = ' + aSubject + ' | aTopic = ' + aTopic + ' | aData = ' + aData);
            var httpChannel = aSubject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
            var requestUrl = httpChannel.URI.spec
var index = requestUrl.indexOf('&list=');
            if (requestUrl.indexOf('youtube.com') > -1 && index > -1) {
               console.log(requestUrl);
var temp = requestUrl.slice(0, index);
               httpChannel.redirectTo(Services.io.newURI(temp, null, null));
            }
        },
        reg: function () {
            Services.obs.addObserver(observers['http-on-modify-request'], 'http-on-modify-request', false);
        },
        unreg: function () {
            Services.obs.removeObserver(observers['http-on-modify-request'], 'http-on-modify-request');
        }
    }
};
```

or instead of the redirectTo line you can do `httpChannel.cancel(Cr.NS_BINDING_ABORTED);` than get that `loadConext` and change the url.

#### To start observing

To start start obseving all requests do this (for example on startup of your addon)

```
for (var o in observers) {
    observers[o].reg();
}
```

#### To stop observing

Its important to stop observring (make sure to run this at least on shutdown of addon, you dont want to leave the observer registered for memory reasons)

```
for (var o in observers) {
    observers[o].unreg();
}
```

Comment: I copied https://github.com/jbutz/facebook-ssl/blob/master/lib/main.js, made some changes to get this, https://github.com/thinker3/addons/blob/master/modify_url/lib/main.js. I don't know where or how to unregister. I tested your code, however, I don't know how to get it work. I started to write addon two days ago, so I know a little about it.

Comment: Try copy pasting my code above exactly and mofiy from there.

Comment: The commented out code at bottom looks to me like it would work. You have a mistake on this line `get observerService() {` why the space? i think u mean `get: observerService() {`

Comment: hm im not sure man. when you copied pasted my code it didnt work? you can try running it from scratchpad with environment set to browser, it worked for me